# What should be the correct way to store the scraped data for TextField

Tags: django, templates, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to Scrap data from websites lets say for instance **SO**.

For example on **SO** we write inside a **Text Editor** but on the **backend** it is stored in a **Text Field** with proper **HTML** markup and rendered whenever need. I am facing similar situation in which I have to scrap data for a **Text Field** so my question is how do I apply formatting before saving.

I am thinking of having a sample template and use Template engine like [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) to fill the **context** and then finally save it. Is this the correct approach. Maybe someone can share his experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with django already, why not using the framework templates?

Assume that you have a `text_field_template.html` in your templates directory, you can render it with the content in the model save method:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class MyModel(models.Model):

   the_text_field = models.TextField...

   def save(self,context):
      self.the_text_field = render_to_string(text_field_template.html,context)
      super(MyModel,self).save()
```

You can of course add a template arg, so you `save(context,template)`.

It's better to render the template in the "save" method, since a typical DB activity has fewer writes than reads. If you save this field once, then read 10, or 100 times, it makes sense to render on saving.

You may have a different use case:

1. If the context is based on current and changing data, which is available only when the user reads the field, then you must render when pulling the record.
2. An application that uses the field once, one save - one read -  one delete. It doesn't really matter if you render on the save or the read.

etc.

Note that from a safety point of view, you must escape everything before it goes to the DB.

Comment: Actually my concern is approach. Is this the correct approach, First extract the data fill my own template with the extracted data then save ????

Comment: I will first scrap the data using awesome `Scrapy framework` then render the template with scraped data and then pass it to the item field which can saved it in pipeline in `Django` text field.